# Executable crash only on machine upgraded from Windows 8 Enterprise to Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, activex

I have a C++ executable created in VS2013 and runs on all windows OS except Windows 8.1 Enterprise(which is upgraded from Windows 8) it crashes. If we use freshly installed Windows 8.1 Enterprise Edition it works.

- [Pass] `Windows 8` Enterprise Edition
- [Pass] `Windows 8.1` Enterprise Edition
- [Fail] `Windows 8` Enterprise Edition upgraded to `Windows 8.1` Enterprise

Now on the upgraded Windows 8.1 machine breakpoints gets fired for **`Memory Corruption(0xc0000374) RtlReportCriticalFailure`**.

*I cant figure out what could be the reason for crash?*

1. is crash at **`RtlpInitializeLfhBitmapData()`**
2. is it because windows was upgraded from 8 to 8.1

***About exe***

> ActiveX C++ code is about a RDP connection to a desktop of remote machine
>   [***`IMsTscAx::Connect()`***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382831(v=vs.85).aspx).

***Event Logs***

```
Faulting application name: Launch.exe, version: 1.0.0.2,
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version:  6.3.9600.18202
Exception code: 0xc0000374 
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f1b70 
Faulting process id: 0xa828 
Faulting application start time: 0x01d240c001c0c1fe 
Faulting application path: Launch.exe 
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 44d0ff4d-acb3-11e6-82b0-2016d86d6542
```

***Crash Trace***

```
00007FF892E1184C  call        RtlInitUnicodeString (07FF892D4AB80h)  
00007FF892E11851  lea         r9,[rbp+8]  
00007FF892E11855  lea         rcx,[rbp+18h]  
00007FF892E11859  xor         edx,edx  
00007FF892E1185B  mov         r8d,20019h  
00007FF892E11861  call        LdrpOpenKey (07FF892D43D88h)  
00007FF892E11866  test        eax,eax  
00007FF892E11868  js          _RtlpRemovePendingDeleteLanguages+13Ch (07FF892E11920h)  
00007FF892E1186E  mov         ebx,r15d  
00007FF892E11871  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+8]  
00007FF892E11875  lea         rax,[rbp+10h]  
00007FF892E11879  lea         r9,[rbp+40h]  
00007FF892E1187D  mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax  
00007FF892E11882  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF892E11885  mov         edx,ebx  
00007FF892E11887  mov         dword ptr [rsp+20h],200h  
00007FF892E1188F  call        NtEnumerateKey (07FF892DB09D0h)  
00007FF892E11894  mov         esi,eax  
00007FF892E11896  test        eax,eax  
00007FF892E11898  js          _RtlpRemovePendingDeleteLanguages+120h (07FF892E11904h)  
00007FF892E1189A  mov         edx,dword ptr [rbp+4Ch]  
00007FF892E1189D  lea         rcx,[rdx+18h]  
00007FF892E118A1  cmp         rcx,1FEh  
00007FF892E118A8  jae         _RtlpRemovePendingDeleteLanguages+120h (07FF892E11904h)  
00007FF892E118AA  shr         rdx,1  
00007FF892E118AD  lea         r9,[rbp]  
00007FF892E118B1  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF892E118B4  mov         word ptr [rbp+rdx*2+50h],r15w  
00007FF892E118BA  lea         rdx,[rbp+50h]  
00007FF892E118BE  mov         rcx,rdi  
00007FF892E118C1  call        RtlpMuiRegGetInstalledLanguageIndexByName (07FF892D47408h)  
00007FF892E118C6  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118C7  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118C8  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118C9  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118CA  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118CB  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118CC  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118CD  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118CE  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118CF  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D0  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D1  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D2  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D3  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D4  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D5  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D6  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D7  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D8  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118D9  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118DA  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118DB  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118DC  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118DD  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118DE  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118DF  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118E0  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118E1  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118E2  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118E3  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E118E4  sbb         byte ptr [r8-75h],r9b  
00007FF892E118E8  adc         byte ptr [rax+0FFDFh],dil  
00007FF892E118EF  and         word ptr [rcx+rdx],ax  
00007FF892E118F3  mov         rax,qword ptr [rdi+18h]  
00007FF892E118F7  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rax+10h]  
00007FF892E118FB  mov         eax,8000h  
00007FF892E11900  or          word ptr [rcx+rdx],ax  
00007FF892E11904  inc         ebx  
00007FF892E11906  cmp         esi,8000001Ah  
00007FF892E1190C  jne         _RtlpRemovePendingDeleteLanguages+8Dh (07FF892E11871h)  
00007FF892E11912  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+8]  
00007FF892E11916  test        rcx,rcx  
00007FF892E11919  je          _RtlpRemovePendingDeleteLanguages+13Ch (07FF892E11920h)  
00007FF892E1191B  call        NtClose (07FF892DB07A0h)  
00007FF892E11920  xor         eax,eax  
00007FF892E11922  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+240h]  
00007FF892E11929  xor         rcx,rsp  
00007FF892E1192C  call        __security_check_cookie (07FF892DA1A80h)  
00007FF892E11931  lea         r11,[rsp+2A0h]  
00007FF892E11939  mov         rbx,qword ptr [r11+38h]  
00007FF892E1193D  mov         rsi,qword ptr [r11+40h]  
00007FF892E11941  mov         rsp,r11  
00007FF892E11944  pop         r15  
00007FF892E11946  pop         r14  
00007FF892E11948  pop         r12  
00007FF892E1194A  pop         rdi  
00007FF892E1194B  pop         rbp  
00007FF892E1194C  ret  
00007FF892E1194D  int         3  
00007FF892E1194E  int         3  
00007FF892E1194F  int         3  
00007FF892E11950  int         3  
00007FF892E11951  int         3  
00007FF892E11952  int         3  
00007FF892E11953  int         3  
00007FF892E11954  mov         eax,r8d  
00007FF892E11957  mov         r8,rcx  
00007FF892E1195A  test        rcx,rcx  
00007FF892E1195D  je          _SafeReallocBlob+48h (07FF892E1199Ch)  
00007FF892E1195F  mov         ecx,eax  
00007FF892E11961  mov         eax,r9d  
00007FF892E11964  imul        rcx,rax  
00007FF892E11968  mov         eax,0FFFFFFFFh  
00007FF892E1196D  cmp         rcx,rax  
00007FF892E11970  ja          _SafeReallocBlob+48h (07FF892E1199Ch)  
00007FF892E11972  lea         eax,[rcx+rdx]  
00007FF892E11975  cmp         eax,edx  
00007FF892E11977  jb          _SafeReallocBlob+48h (07FF892E1199Ch)  
00007FF892E11979  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+38h]  
00007FF892E1197E  test        rcx,rcx  
00007FF892E11981  je          _SafeReallocBlob+31h (07FF892E11985h)  
00007FF892E11983  mov         dword ptr [rcx],eax  
00007FF892E11985  mov         rcx,qword ptr gs:[60h]  
00007FF892E1198E  mov         r9d,eax  
00007FF892E11991  xor         edx,edx  
00007FF892E11993  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx+30h]  
00007FF892E11997  jmp         RtlReAllocateHeap (07FF892D4F040h)  
00007FF892E1199C  xor         eax,eax  
00007FF892E1199E  ret  
00007FF892E1199F  int         3  
00007FF892E119A0  int         3  
00007FF892E119A1  int         3  
00007FF892E119A2  int         3  
00007FF892E119A3  int         3  
00007FF892E119A4  int         3  
00007FF892E119A5  int         3  
00007FF892E119A6  int         3  
00007FF892E119A7  int         3  
00007FF892E119A8  int         3  
00007FF892E119A9  int         3  
00007FF892E119AA  int         3  
00007FF892E119AB  int         3  
00007FF892E119AC  int         3  
00007FF892E119AD  int         3  
00007FF892E119AE  int         3  
00007FF892E119AF  int         3  
RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey:
00007FF892E119B0  jmp         NtDeleteKey (07FF892DB12E0h)  
00007FF892E119B5  int         3  
00007FF892E119B6  int         3  
00007FF892E119B7  int         3  
00007FF892E119B8  int         3  
00007FF892E119B9  int         3  
00007FF892E119BA  int         3  
00007FF892E119BB  int         3  
00007FF892E119BC  int         3  
00007FF892E119BD  int         3  
00007FF892E119BE  int         3  
00007FF892E119BF  int         3  
RtlpDebugPageHeapCreate:
00007FF892E119C0  mov         rax,rsp  
00007FF892E119C3  mov         qword ptr [rax+8],rbx  
00007FF892E119C7  mov         qword ptr [rax+10h],rbp  
00007FF892E119CB  mov         qword ptr [rax+18h],rsi  
00007FF892E119CF  mov         qword ptr [rax+20h],rdi  
00007FF892E119D3  push        r14  
00007FF892E119D5  sub         rsp,30h  
00007FF892E119D9  mov         rbx,qword ptr [RtlpDebugPageHeapTable+38h (07FF892E4EC58h)]  
00007FF892E119E0  mov         r14d,ecx  
00007FF892E119E3  mov         rdi,r9  
00007FF892E119E6  mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF892E119E9  mov         rsi,r8  
00007FF892E119EC  mov         rbp,rdx  
00007FF892E119EF  call        qword ptr [__guard_check_icall_fptr (07FF892E611D0h)]  
00007FF892E119F5  mov         r9,rdi  
00007FF892E119F8  mov         r8,rsi  
00007FF892E119FB  mov         rdx,rbp  
00007FF892E119FE  mov         ecx,r14d  
00007FF892E11A01  mov         rax,rbx  
00007FF892E11A04  mov         rbx,qword ptr [rsp+40h]  
00007FF892E11A09  mov         rbp,qword ptr [rsp+48h]  
00007FF892E11A0E  mov         rsi,qword ptr [rsp+50h]  
00007FF892E11A13  mov         rdi,qword ptr [rsp+58h]  
00007FF892E11A18  add         rsp,30h  
00007FF892E11A1C  pop         r14  
00007FF892E11A1E  jmp         rax  
00007FF892E11A21  int         3  
00007FF892E11A22  int         3  
00007FF892E11A23  int         3  
00007FF892E11A24  int         3  
00007FF892E11A25  int         3  
00007FF892E11A26  int         3  
00007FF892E11A27  int         3  
00007FF892E11A28  int         3  
00007FF892E11A29  int         3  
00007FF892E11A2A  int         3  
00007FF892E11A2B  int         3  
00007FF892E11A2C  int         3  
00007FF892E11A2D  int         3  
00007FF892E11A2E  int         3  
00007FF892E11A2F  int         3  
RtlpDebugPageHeapDestroy:
00007FF892E11A30  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx  
00007FF892E11A35  push        rdi  
00007FF892E11A36  sub         rsp,20h  
00007FF892E11A3A  mov         rbx,qword ptr [RtlpDebugPageHeapTable+40h (07FF892E4EC60h)]  
00007FF892E11A41  mov         rdi,rcx  
00007FF892E11A44  mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF892E11A47  call        qword ptr [__guard_check_icall_fptr (07FF892E611D0h)]  
00007FF892E11A4D  mov         rcx,rdi  
00007FF892E11A50  mov         rax,rbx  
00007FF892E11A53  mov         rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
00007FF892E11A58  add         rsp,20h  
00007FF892E11A5C  pop         rdi  
00007FF892E11A5D  jmp         rax  
00007FF892E11A60  int         3  
00007FF892E11A61  int         3  
00007FF892E11A62  int         3  
00007FF892E11A63  int         3  
00007FF892E11A64  int         3  
00007FF892E11A65  int         3  
00007FF892E11A66  int         3  
00007FF892E11A67  int         3  
RtlpInitializeLfhBitmapData:
00007FF892E11A68  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx  
00007FF892E11A6D  push        rdi  
00007FF892E11A6E  sub         rsp,20h  
00007FF892E11A72  mov         rbx,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FF892E11A75  mov         rdi,qword ptr [rcx+8]  
00007FF892E11A79  xor         edx,edx  
00007FF892E11A7B  lea         r8,[rbx+7]  
00007FF892E11A7F  mov         rcx,rdi  
00007FF892E11A82  shr         r8,3  
00007FF892E11A86  call        memset (07FF892DB4640h)  
00007FF892E11A8B  mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF892E11A8E  and         ecx,3Fh  
00007FF892E11A91  je          RtlpInitializeLfhBitmapData+41h (07FF892E11AA9h)  
00007FF892E11A93  mov         eax,1  
00007FF892E11A98  shr         rbx,6  
00007FF892E11A9C  shl         rax,cl  
00007FF892E11A9F  dec         rax  
00007FF892E11AA2  not         rax  
00007FF892E11AA5  or          qword ptr [rdi+rbx*8],rax  
00007FF892E11AA9  mov         rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
00007FF892E11AAE  add         rsp,20h  
00007FF892E11AB2  pop         rdi  
00007FF892E11AB3  ret  
00007FF892E11AB4  int         3  
00007FF892E11AB5  int         3  
00007FF892E11AB6  int         3  
00007FF892E11AB7  int         3  
00007FF892E11AB8  int         3  
00007FF892E11AB9  int         3  
00007FF892E11ABA  int         3  
00007FF892E11ABB  int         3  
RtlIsAnyDebuggerPresent:
00007FF892E11ABC  mov         rax,qword ptr gs:[60h]  
00007FF892E11AC5  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AC6  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AC7  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AC8  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AC9  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11ACA  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11ACB  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11ACC  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11ACD  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11ACE  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11ACF  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AD0  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AD1  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AD2  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AD3  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AD4  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AD5  ?? ?? 
00007FF892E11AD6  add         ecx,dword ptr [rdi]  
00007FF892E11AD8  xchg        eax,esp  
00007FF892E11AD9  rol         bl,0CCh  
00007FF892E11ADC  int         3  
00007FF892E11ADD  int         3  
00007FF892E11ADE  int         3  
00007FF892E11ADF  int         3  
00007FF892E11AE0  int         3  
00007FF892E11AE1  int         3  
00007FF892E11AE2  int         3  
00007FF892E11AE3  int         3  
RtlReportCriticalFailure:
00007FF892E11AE4  mov         qword ptr [rsp+18h],rbx  
00007FF892E11AE9  mov         qword ptr [rsp+10h],rdx  
00007FF892E11AEE  push        rdi  
00007FF892E11AEF  sub         rsp,100h  
00007FF892E11AF6  mov         rax,qword ptr [__security_cookie (07FF892E64388h)]  
00007FF892E11AFD  xor         rax,rsp  
00007FF892E11B00  mov         qword ptr [rsp+0F0h],rax  
00007FF892E11B08  mov         rdi,rdx  
00007FF892E11B0B  mov         ebx,ecx  
00007FF892E11B0D  mov         dword ptr [rsp+28h],ecx  
00007FF892E11B11  call        RtlIsAnyDebuggerPresent (07FF892E11ABCh)  
00007FF892E11B16  test        al,al  
00007FF892E11B18  je          RtlReportCriticalFailure+5Ah (07FF892E11B3Eh)  
00007FF892E11B1A  mov         r9d,ecx  
00007FF892E11B1D  lea         r8,[string "Critical error detected %lx\n" (07FF892DBE3A0h)]  
00007FF892E11B24  xor         edx,edx  
00007FF892E11B26  lea         ecx,[rdx+65h]  
00007FF892E11B29  call        DbgPrintEx (07FF892D70C00h)  
00007FF892E11B2E  nop  
00007FF892E11B2F  int         3  
00007FF892E11B30  jmp         RtlReportCriticalFailure+5Ah (07FF892E11B3Eh)  
00007FF892E11B32  mov         rdi,qword ptr [rsp+118h]  
00007FF892E11B3A  mov         ebx,dword ptr [rsp+28h]  
00007FF892E11B3E  mov         dword ptr [rsp+50h],ebx  
00007FF892E11B42  mov         ecx,1  
00007FF892E11B47  mov         dword ptr [rsp+54h],ecx  
00007FF892E11B4B  and         qword ptr [rsp+58h],0  
00007FF892E11B51  lea         rax,[RtlRaiseException (07FF892D738E0h)]  
00007FF892E11B58  mov         qword ptr [rsp+60h],rax  
00007FF892E11B5D  mov         dword ptr [rsp+68h],ecx  
00007FF892E11B61  mov         qword ptr [rsp+70h],rdi  
00007FF892E11B66  lea         rcx,[rsp+50h]  
00007FF892E11B6B  call        RtlRaiseException (07FF892D738E0h)  

==============================>> crash breakpoint

00007FF892E11B70  jmp         RtlReportCriticalFailure+8Eh (07FF892E11B72h)  

==============================>> crash breakpoint

00007FF892E11B72  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0F0h]  
00007FF892E11B7A  xor         rcx,rsp  
00007FF892E11B7D  call        __security_check_cookie (07FF892DA1A80h)  
00007FF892E11B82  mov         rbx,qword ptr [rsp+120h]  
00007FF892E11B8A  add         rsp,100h  
00007FF892E11B91  pop         rdi  
00007FF892E11B92  ret  
00007FF892E11B93  push        rbp  
00007FF892E11B95  sub         rsp,20h  
00007FF892E11B99  mov         rbp,rdx  
00007FF892E11B9C  mov         qword ptr [rbp+40h],rcx  
00007FF892E11BA0  mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FF892E11BA3  mov         edx,dword ptr [rax]  
00007FF892E11BA5  mov         dword ptr [rbp+38h],edx  
00007FF892E11BA8  mov         qword ptr [rbp+30h],rcx  
00007FF892E11BAC  mov         dword ptr [rbp+20h],edx  
00007FF892E11BAF  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+30h]  
00007FF892E11BB3  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+30h]  
00007FF892E11BB7  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF892E11BBA  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdx+8]  
00007FF892E11BBE  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FF892E11BC1  call        RtlReportException (07FF892DEAF60h)  
00007FF892E11BC6  mov         edx,dword ptr [rbp+20h]  
00007FF892E11BC9  or          rcx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh  
00007FF892E11BCD  call        NtTerminateProcess (07FF892DB0970h)  
00007FF892E11BD2  mov         eax,1  
00007FF892E11BD7  add         rsp,20h  
00007FF892E11BDB  pop         rbp  
00007FF892E11BDC  ret  
00007FF892E11BDD  int         3  
00007FF892E11BDE  int         3  
00007FF892E11BDF  int         3  
00007FF892E11BE0  int         3  
00007FF892E11BE1  int         3  
00007FF892E11BE2  int         3  
00007FF892E11BE3  int         3  
RtlpCreateExecutionRequiredRequest:
00007FF892E11BE4  mov         rax,rsp  
00007FF892E11BE7  mov         qword ptr [rax+8],rbx  
00007FF892E11BEB  mov         qword ptr [rax+10h],rsi  
00007FF892E11BEF  push        rdi  
00007FF892E11BF0  sub         rsp,0A0h  
00007FF892E11BF7  and         qword ptr [rsp+20h],0  
00007FF892E11BFD  mov         ebx,40h  
00007FF892E11C02  mov         rdi,rdx  
00007FF892E11C05  lea         r8,[rax-48h]  
00007FF892E11C09  xor         edx,edx  
00007FF892E11C0B  mov         r9d,ebx  
00007FF892E11C0E  mov         rsi,rcx  
00007FF892E11C11  mov         qword ptr [rax-48h],rbx  
00007FF892E11C15  call        NtQueryInformationProcess (07FF892DB0840h)  
00007FF892E11C1A  test        eax,eax  
00007FF892E11C1C  js          RtlpCreateExecutionRequiredRequest+0CCh (07FF892E11CB0h)  
00007FF892E11C22  test        byte ptr [rsp+98h],bl  
00007FF892E11C29  jne         RtlpCreateExecutionRequiredRequest+4Fh (07FF892E11C33h)  
00007FF892E11C2B  and         qword ptr [rdi],0  
00007FF892E11C2F  xor         eax,eax  
00007FF892E11C31  jmp         RtlpCreateExecutionRequiredRequest+0CCh (07FF892E11CB0h)  
00007FF892E11C33  and         dword ptr [rsp+30h],0  
00007FF892E11C38  lea         rdx,[string L"QueryDebugInformatio"... (07FF892DBE3C0h)]  
00007FF892E11C3F  lea         rcx,[rsp+38h]  
00007FF892E11C44  mov         dword ptr [rsp+34h],1  
00007FF892E11C4C  call        RtlInitUnicodeString (07FF892D4AB80h)  
00007FF892E11C51  mov         r8d,28h  
00007FF892E11C57  lea         r9,[rsp+0C0h]  
00007FF892E11C5F  lea         rdx,[rsp+30h]  
00007FF892E11C64  lea         ecx,[r8+20h]  
00007FF892E11C68  mov         dword ptr [rsp+20h],8  
00007FF892E11C70  call        NtPowerInformation (07FF892DB0CA0h)  
00007FF892E11C75  mov         ebx,eax  
00007FF892E11C77  test        eax,eax  
00007FF892E11C79  js          RtlpCreateExecutionRequiredRequest+0CAh (07FF892E11CAEh)  
00007FF892E11C7B  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h]  
00007FF892E11C83  mov         r8b,1  
00007FF892E11C86  mov         rdx,rsi  
00007FF892E11C89  call        RtlpSetClearExecutionRequiredRequest (07FF892E11CF4h)  
00007FF892E11C8E  mov         ebx,eax  
00007FF892E11C90  test        eax,eax  
00007FF892E11C92  jns         RtlpCreateExecutionRequiredRequest+0BFh (07FF892E11CA3h)  
00007FF892E11C94  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h]  
00007FF892E11C9C  call        NtClose (07FF892DB07A0h)  
00007FF892E11CA1  jmp         RtlpCreateExecutionRequiredRequest+0CAh (07FF892E11CAEh)  
00007FF892E11CA3  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h]  
00007FF892E11CAB  mov         qword ptr [rdi],rax  
00007FF892E11CAE  mov         eax,ebx  
00007FF892E11CB0  lea         r11,[rsp+0A0h]  
00007FF892E11CB8  mov         rbx,qword ptr [r11+10h]  
00007FF892E11CBC  mov         rsi,qword ptr [r11+18h]  
00007FF892E11CC0  mov         rsp,r11  
00007FF892E11CC3  pop         rdi  
00007FF892E11CC4  ret  
00007FF892E11CC5  int         3  
00007FF892E11CC6  int         3  
00007FF892E11CC7  int         3
```

***Update: 1 (24 November 2016)***

I tried running mstsc.exe(remoteApp) and the behavior was same. I found some information on this issue at **[forum link](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r30702359-MS-patch-installing-old-vulnerable-version-of-ntdll-dll)** which say that it is because the **`ntdll.dll 6.3.9600.18202`** from KB3147071 and KB3146723 updates are slightly different at a binary level.

> ***Is there any problem with my mstsc or ntdll?***

```
Faulting application name: mstsc.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x5450434f
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18202, time stamp: 0x569e7d02
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f1b70
Faulting process id: 0xef0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d241a5a2f9553b
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: e55dc0b4-ad98-11e6-82b1-2016d86d6542
```

Comment: This sounds like undefined behaviour. I suppose there is a subtle bug in your software and on the platforms where it works you are just getting away with it.

Comment: `c0000374` - this is `STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION` - `A heap has been corrupted.` - very common case. stack trace here almost always not help, because heap was corrupted early and now this only detected. this bug hard research even on local comp and almost impossible remote.

Comment: Some of your code corrupted your heap. The 'crash' happens at a later time, when the heap manager realizes, that something went wrong. Since you apparently can reproduce the bug, try to run your application under the surveillance of [Application Verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538115.aspx). It will help you gather information, as soon as the heap gets corrupted.

Comment: Try putting AfxMessageBoxes in your App, or write to a log.  Place the markers every few lines of code and see where you are going wrong.  I found out that I had a corrupt APS file this way.